# increase DIV container with foreach

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, foreach

Java in my header lists:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv(idInfo) {
        var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
            sel[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #container1, #user_elements {
        display : none;
        border : 0px solid blue;
        height : 100%;
        overflow : hidden;
    }
</style>
```

I don't need a bunch of containers I am just using this to display the new link clicked in the main DIV.

This is my Links code:

```
<div id="linkDiv">
    <?php
        $dir = "./modules";
        $folders = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
        $i=1;
        foreach ($folders as $item) {
            if ($item->isDir() && !$item->isDot()){
    ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('<?php echo $i; ?>');return false"><?php echo $item->getFilename(); ?></a><br />
    <?php
                $i++;
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is the display location:

```
<div id="divLinks">
    <?php
        $path = "./modules";
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
        foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
            if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
                echo $fileinfo->getFilename().'<br>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    <!-- Increase container# by 1 for every foreach loop -->
    <div id="container1"><?php $fileinfo->getFilename() ?></div>
</div>

<!-- So if $path = Directory1 and Directory2 then the output would look like: -->
<div id="divLinks">
    <div id="container1">Container #1<p>$dir/Directory1/index.php</div>
    <div id="container2">Container #2<p>$dir/Directory2/index.php</div>
</div>
```

So what I need to is while the

```
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
```

Finds directories the Main or display container increases by 1

Comment: Java? You mean javascript?

Comment: Sorry yes java script

Comment: It is one word, _Javascript_. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
<div id="divLinks">
    <?php
        $path = "./modules";
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
        $count= 1;
        foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
            if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
                echo '<div id="container' . $count . '">' . $fileinfo->getFilename() . '</div>';
                //increase counter by 1
                $count++;
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I needed to figure out, also my Active Directory link was failing causing some of my code to fail. I forgot to add in here that I needed to include in the DIV. Your code gave me the right way to find my problem. I could not figure out if what came before the foreach was the problem or what I was trying to code. Thanks for your in put and so you can see what I did and for future refrance here is how I changed the code. Thanks again! (I'ed give you rep if I could figure out how :P)

```
<div id="divLinks">
<?php
    $path = "./modules";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    $count= 1;
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            echo '<div id="container' . $count . '">'; include "$path/" . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "/index.php";
            echo "</div>";
            //increase counter by 1
            $count++;
        }
    }
?>
```